# Why make_tie is not a thing?

Tags: c++, c++14, stdtuple

There is a popular idiom using `std::tie` to implement comparison operators:

```
// foo.h
struct Foo {
  int a, b;
  string c;

  bool operator<(const Foo& rhs) const;
};

// foo.cc
bool Foo::operator<(const Foo& rhs) const {
  return tie(a, b, c) < tie(rhs.a, rhs.b, rhs.c);
}
```

[E.g. it's widely used in Chromium](https://cs.chromium.org/search/?q=std::tie&sq=package:chromium&type=cs)

However it requires copying the list of members, so why not write a helper function:

```
static auto MakeTie(const Foo& x) {
  return tie(x.a, x.b, x.c);
}
bool Foo::operator<(const Foo& rhs) const {
  return MakeTie(*this) < MakeTie(rhs);
}

// or, in foo.h
auto MakeTie() const;
// and in foo.cc
auto Foo::MakeTie() const { ... }
```

(btw such member function cannot be called from any other translation unit)

So, why do I see hundreds of such `tie(a, b, c) < tie(copy-pasta)` pairs, is there a reason behind this?

Comment: with "copying the list of members" do you mean you have to copy the parameters list in the code? because `tie` is not doing copies. then i dont understand your question. If you like, of course you can write a `MakeTie`, though you would need a different one for each type

Comment: There is no necessary reflection mechanism in C++ that will allow you to list all data members.

Comment: also in the code you link I dont see a `tie( some parameters) < tie (exact same parameters)` but rather `tie (some parameters) < tie (some other parameters)` so I dont think this helper function would really help, it would rather obfuscate the code imho

Comment: Why aren't more projects using this idiom? We can only speculate. I think this question only has opinionated answers.

Comment: `make_tie` isn't a thing because there is no way to build it.  There is no reflection in C++ so you would have to write it yourself.  I've seen a private `as_tuple` helper function used in place of `tie`

Comment: @user463035818 I think the argument is that one parameter (x2) is better than 192 parameters (x2). Particularly as in the latter case, almost all of it is literally repeated information, whereas in the former case none of it is.

Comment: It's not clear to me what answer you're possibly looking for. People didn't think it was worthwhile to factor that out. Maybe in some cases that was a bad decision. Sometimes, refactoring is more trouble than it's worth. Shrug?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I guess you exaggerated to make your point, but when a class has 192 members i would worry about other things than how to tie them in a nice way

Comment: @user463035818 I did also note that in my answer ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yep wrote the comment before reading it

Comment: @user463035818 Does your evil know no bounds?

Comment: Hey, @user463035818 didn't make any cracks about "`tie` fighters" so how evil can they be?

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, if your class has so many members that doubling up `tie` is problematic, then you may have a design smell anyway.

I *would* tend to agree that this is a bit of an annoyance, but remember that it's not the reason for `tie`'s being. There is no such thing as "a `tie`"; "tie" here is a verb, a way to describe how expressions are being "tied together" into what is actually a tuple of references.

You can of course write your own replacement for `tie` that knows how all the relevant members of your class, so that this does not need writing out twice. You could call it `members_as_tuple`. It's up to you as to whether you want to do that, just as it is up to you whether to make *any* function to avoid some particular duplicated code.

Certainly, though, without reflection, C++ cannot do this for you in the general case, so that's why such a facility isn't provided out of the box.

*tl;dr: You've already shown the best (only?) way to do it, but I wouldn't call it `make_tie`.*

---

As for why people aren't doing this more, well, that's unanswerable. They probably just didn't think of it, or didn't think they needed it, and were probably right.

Comment: … and then some members may not be relevant. Or may point to / contain the relevant member. Or source-order might not be comparison-order. ...

Comment: @Deduplicator Right.

Comment: `members_as_tuple_of_references`, FTFY.

Comment: IDK, maybe `std::tie(a,b,c) < std::tie(a,b,c)` would inline better. Maybe `auto TieUp() const;` won't inline at all on certain popular compiler.

Comment: @Abyx : That's conceivable as well